# Is there a complete list of AWS resource actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a list of AWS resource actions anywhere? For example, if I look at one of the AWS policies for sqs read only access I see a list of actions. But I can't find the FULL list of actions for this resource despite searching for what seems like forever. Some of the API reference pages refer to the necessary action permission (like for create queue) but not all. I had a custom policy and found out I needed the GetQueueUrl action. So in summary, I just want to know if there is ANYWHERE that AWS lists out all the actions for each service?

```
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
                    "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
                    "sqs:ListDeadLetterSourceQueues",
                    "sqs:ListQueues"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: IAM -> Policy -> Create Policy in the AWS console. The GUI policy editor shows all actions for particular resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this shoudl work for you :-

1. go to IAM
2. under policies -> create policy.
3. choose a service -> under action -> **expand all**

you can see all the actions associated with that service through console.

also you can use this https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html, select your service and you will be able to see actioned defined for that service in a tabular form

Comment: Thank you, the doc you referenced is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

See [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsqs.html). It contains the full list of [Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsqs.html#amazonsqs-actions-as-permissions).

For all AWS services, start with [Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html).